# How to calculate average of first two highest number of a range?

Tags: excel

write a formula in cell E2 to calculate the average of two highest cumulative numbers among three students after converting the obtained numbers in hundred

[image: here is my excel data]

Comment: Sum them up and then divide by the count of them. It is the same like the [average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average) for numbers which are not  the *"first two highest"*. While that combination itself is a bit conflicting to my eyes, fortunately it was not asked how to evaluate them. vfc

Answer (score 1):

To get the maximum you can use `max` and to get the second largest number you can use `large`. Add the two numbers and divide them by two:

```
=(MAX(B3:D5)+LARGE(B3:D5,2))/2
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot follow your question fully. Do you want the top 2 grades, even if they are from the same student? Then @Ralph answer does it. It does not however take into account the 30% values you have in row 1.

If you want the top 2 student grades (e.g. each student can only take 1 place). Do this:

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvABw.png)